# CSS, Is there anyway to prevent the children of creating their own stacking context?

Tags: css

Simply I want the content to scroll under the fixed header but the modal in the top of the header. if I removed the `position: relative;` from the `.content` it will work fine but I can't remove it in my real project there are hundreds of children using it and other properties creating new stacking context. thanks for help.

here is html html:

```
<div>
  <div class="header">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="modal">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 115px;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

and also [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yr0fartg/)

Comment: Self contained question please. Having fiddle link is good, but not so if the link rot.

Comment: are we good now  ??

Comment: simply give a "z-index:999;" to your header

Comment: z-index would fix it. but I need more clarity on this statement `Simply I want the content to scroll under the fixed header but the modal in the top of the header. `

Comment: I think z-index will not fix it. the problem is I have to give the fixed header higher z-index so the content scroll under the header (make sense ? yes! ). working fine so far. but when the modal is open which is in the real project is full screen modal. with transparent black background.  it would show under the fixed header. And  of course full screen model should fill the whole screen. so I have to give the modal's parent (`content`) higher z-index so the modal show above the header.  Both content and header need higher z-index than each other 'can't be both higher each other'

Comment: I am trying to simplify  here. this is similar view click the first picture to see the [modal](https://lukasz-galka.github.io/ngx-gallery-demo/) . If this view has header fixed in the top, it will cover the close button on the top. if I gave the gallery high which is the content higher z-index. when the user scroll the gallery will show in the top of the header 'it should scroll under the header'!! I hope it's clear now :)

Comment: @VishalSharma. I hope that help you to understand the problem